# Unable to render SurfaceView inside RecyclerView. Implementing group video calling using Agora.io

Tags: android, surfaceview, agora.io

My requirement is to have a bottom scrolling for all users. I have added recyclerview for this. Problem occurs when I am trying to add surfaceview provided from sdk to recycler; it renders to black color view.

I have also tried adding following properties to surfaceview

```
@NotNull
@Override
public UsersSurfaceViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                             int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(
            parent.getContext());
    View v =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cell_video_call, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    VideoModel model = values.get(position);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams videoLayoutParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    SurfaceView surfaceView = model.getSurface();
    surfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    holder.relContainer.addView(surfaceView, videoLayoutParams);
}
```

Also my holder.relContainer is having fixed height and width.

Comment: Have you made sure to setup the remote video correctly? Here is the relevant function in the documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#a0e9f693c9bc2ccb91554c2c7dc6b7140

Comment: yes, I am able to render surface view for remote, if mRelCantainer.addView(surface,layoutParams); where mRelContainer is a Relative Layout within fragment layout. This same surface is unable to render within recycler view.

Comment: I have implemented something similar using recyclerview as well. You can take a look and let me know if this proves helpful: https://github.com/samyak-jain/uikitv2/blob/master/agorauikit/src/main/java/io/agora/agorauikit/ui/mincontainer/AgoraRecyclerView.kt

Comment: @Samyak I solved this yesterday, turns out it was minor execution sequence error. Thanks for your help, and I will definitely have a look at uikittv repo.

Comment: @Dhaval Patel Hi,
i have same issue can you please tell how can you have solved your ishhue.
- thanks